# mistake importing footage

Tags: premiere, video-editor

I am kind of new to video (1 year). When I import video footage into Premiere, I sometimes get duplicate clips. Only the long ones. I think I am not importing my footage correctly. Does it have to do with the clip, if it is long, is really spanning 2 clips? The video is HD, mostly those Canon MTS files. What is the correct way to import into Premiere, just started working with CC (2014) version?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that Premiere is detecting a spanned file and automatically connecting them.  If a file goes beyond 4GB, it may have to be split in to two files due to limitations of the file system used on some memory cards.  It is possible that when you load the file in to Premiere, it recognizes the file was split and puts them back together for both parts that you import.

Comment: This would be what it is - if my memory serves me correctly, a .MTS is usually the wrapper codec for an AVCHD file, which is commonly used on Canon's dedicated video cameras (not their DSLRs, though).

Answer (score 1):

To import into Premiere Pro CC 2014 simply click on the Media Browser tab and select (or multi-select) the files you wish to import. Right-click and click import. Note if you double click on a file, default behavior is to open it for preview.

Here's an adobe help on importing as well:
http://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/importing-assets-tapeless-formats.html

and a how-to video on importing:
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-premiere-pro-cc/import-video-and-audio/

Answer (score 0):

Not paying attention...I was importing the whole card folder by dragging instead of the actual clip files! Some of the clips were long and must have been too big for the filesystem on the card?  When I import the actual clip files through the media browser - Presto - no duplicates and now I see skips in the numerical sequences of the clips - e.g. MTS0000, MTS0001, MTS0004, MTS0007. And the spanned files were always the longest ones.